# Como pegar o Schema de uma Model em um DbContext feito no Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Olá, estou começando a trabalhar com EFCore e estou fazendo um Override no método `SaveChanges()` para que sempre que houver uma manipulação do banco eu puder fazer um log dessa manipulação. Meu problema é que eu estou trabalhando com Schemas no meu banco e não sei como capturar o mesmo de uma `EntityEntry`. Meu código está assim:

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    // construtores...
    // models
    // ...

    public int SaveChanges(int userId)
    {
        var snapshots = ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList();
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        foreach (var s in snapshots)
        {
            var entityName = s.Entity.GetType().Name;
            var schemaName = ""; // como pego isso aqui ?
            var primaryKey = getKey(s);
            var actionName = s.State.ToString();

            var obj = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var props = s.OriginalValues.Properties
                                        .Select(x=> x.Name).ToList();

            foreach (var prop in props)
            {
                var originalValue = s.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                var currentValue = s.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();

                if (originalValue != currentValue)
                    obj.Add(prop, currentValue.ToString());
            }

            Log log = new Log()
            {
                Acao = $"({actionName}) {schemaName}.{entityName}",
                Registro = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj)
            };

            Log.Add(log);

        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChanges(0);
    }

    public virtual int getKey(EntityEntry entity)
    {
        var keyName = Model.FindEntityType(entity.GetType())
                           .FindPrimaryKey().Properties
                           .Select(x => x.Name).Single();

        return (int)entity.GetType().GetProperty(keyName).GetValue(entity, null);
    }
```

Todos os meus models estão estruturados como no exemplo abaixo:

```
[Table("Foo", Schema = "Bar")]
public partial class Foo
{
    // ...
}
```

Como posso saber qual é o Schema da Entidade que estou trabalhando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem essas duas maneiras, uma referente a instância de uma classe e a outra pelo tipo da classe:

***Exemplo:***

```
[Table("Login", Schema = "dbo")]
public class Login
{
    [Key]       
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

- *Pela instância*:

  ```
  Login lg = new Login();
  TableAttribute tableAttribute  = (TableAttribute)lg.GetType()                   
      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute))
      .FirstOrDefault();
  tableAttribute.
  ```
- *Pelo tipo de um classe*:

  ```
  TableAttribute tableAttribute = (TableAttribute)typeof(Login)
       .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute))
      .FirstOrDefault();
  ```

***Nota:*** utilize os dois `namespace`:

- `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;`
- `using System.Reflection;`

***Após a reflexão:***

```
tableAttribute.Schema
tableAttribute.Name
```

***Referencias***

- [Retrieving Information Stored in Attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/retrieving-information-stored-in-attributes)
- [Retrieve custom attribute parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925686/retrieve-custom-attribute-parameter-values)

[Exemplo Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6g1dbu)

Comment: muito obrigado kra, sou "novato" no csharp e ainda mais com EFCore, me ajudou muito!